# How can I hide the backup external usb drive in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, backup

I have one drive where I want to do backup of files. But I don't want that drive to be visible in my computer.

How can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HowToGeek has a tip titled [*Hide Drives from Your Computer in Windows 7 or Vista*](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/hide-drives-from-your-computer-in-windows-vista/) on his website which, via a registry tweak, will allow you to hide the drive yet still be able to access it for your backups

It involves adding a `NoDrives` 32-bit DWORD to the:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

key. The bits in the value of `NoDrives` correspond to the different drive letters. See the article for further details (or ask for clarification by adding comments below).

The article says that it also works on Windows XP, BTW.

Comment: +1 because this does what the OP intended and because you can easily undo it again. (E.g. when you need to restore files from the backup).

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options to do that:

The easiest would be to simply unplug it. Mainly so the backup is physically disconnected and safe from power surges. (Loosing the main computer and the backup if lightning hits would be bad).

However the answer you are probably looking for is to remove the drive letters. Which you can do as follows:

- Right click [My computer] on the desktop
- Select [Manage]
- Go to Storage / disk management
- Select the disk who you no longer want to be visible
- Right click and select [Change drive letters and paths]
- Remove the drive letter.

The drive will no longer show up in explorer.

[image: Several screenshots with arrows on how to remove drive letters]

If you still want to access the drive in a less obvious way to can mount it in a directory from the same place.

Comment: Actually the thing is by backups are running every night on that drive , i wanted to keep connected for backups to run but i don't want to be visible on explorer so that i don't get confused but in cas ei want it , i can access that

Comment: On that case you are better in making backups then I am. :)  I just get a drive from another room (and hopefully overlooked in case of theft) and connect it. But I only do that once per month. -- Note that you can make backups to it without a drive letter.

Comment: i am using delta copy and if i remove the drive letter then its not visible there

Comment: I googled around but I found no way to work around this via Delta copy. :(    (Rsync with cygwin works, but ditching your entire DeltaCopy wrapper for that would be a bad solution). Anyway, I hope someone has an answer for it in the next few days.

Comment: @Hennes: Gee, that doesn't look like Windows-7 you're using... ;-)

Comment: It is win7 though. Just configured so I have no distracting background picture and set to 'Adjust for best performance **and** best appearance'.

Comment: FWIW, you can also use disk management make a "hidden" drive (one without a drive letter assigned to it) appear as a folders on some other drive by assigning it a to path.

Comment: That is what I referred to in my last sentence (more of less hidden below the picture). Sadly DeltaCopy's GUI seems to have problems with it. (See comment 5 up from this one).